# What are the differences between Ethernet Controller and Network Controller?

Tags: networking, ethernet

I have a desktop computer which is not much famous brand "**E-tel iPC**" and I installed ***Windows 2008 R2 Standard Edition*** on that machine.

When I go to the Device Manager I can see ***Ethernet Controller*** and ***Network Controller*** as follows in Other Devices and please advise.

[image: Other Devices]

What are the main differences between them ?

Comment: Ethernet Controller is a kind of Network Controllers. There are another types of Network Controllers - ArcNet, TokenRing, FDDI, etc... If Device manager specifies the device as a Network Controller it cannot determine the precise type of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PCI devices report their class and subclass among other parameters (for recognition before the OS figures out which driver to use for them). The device class 0x02 "Network controller" has [these subclasses](https://pci-ids.ucw.cz/read/PD/02):

- 0x00 – Ethernet network controller
- 0x01 – Token Ring network controller
- 0x02 – FDDI network controller
- etc.
- 0x80 – Some other type of network controller

When the initial list of subclasses was decided on, Ethernet was a fairly popular communications technology and got its own subclass from day one. But Wi-Fi came around quite a bit later – since it *didn't have* a dedicated subclass in this list, many Wi-Fi adapters simply use the 0x80 "Other network controller" subclass.

---

In PCI 3.0 there *is* a 0x0D "Wireless controller" class with [subclasses](https://pci-ids.ucw.cz/read/PD/0d) more suitable for Wi-Fi:

- 0x00…0x12 – subclasses for non-Wi-Fi wireless (Bluetooth, IrDA, etc.)
- 0x20 – 802.11a (5 GHz Wi-Fi) controller
- 0x21 – 802.11b (2.4 GHz Wi-Fi) controller
- 0x80 – Some other type of wireless controller

Presumably a modern dual 2.4 & 5 GHz adapter could flip a coin to choose between 0x20 or 0x21, or it could classify itself as 0x80 "some other subtype" again.

But because the class & subclass aren't really *used* for much else except OS driver lookup, it appears that many manufacturers never saw any reason to switch from the good old 0x0280 "Network controller: Other" device class.